# Celery: dynamic queues at object level

Tags: django, dynamic, concurrency, queue, celery

I'm writing a django app to make polls which uses celery to put under control the voting system. Right now, I have two queues, default and polls, the first one with **concurrency** set to 8 and **the second one set to 1**.

```
$ celery multi start -A myproject.celery default polls -Q:default default -Q:polls polls -c:default 8 -c:polls 1
```

Celery routes:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'polls.tasks.option_add_vote': {
        'queue': 'polls',
    },
    'polls.tasks.option_subtract_vote': {
        'queue': 'polls',
    }
}
```

Task:

```
@app.task
def option_add_vote(pk):
    """
        Updates given option id and its poll increasing vote number by 1.
    """

    option = Option.objects.get(pk=pk)

    try:
        with transaction.atomic():

            option.vote_quantity += 1
            option.save()
            option.poll.total_votes += 1
            option.poll.save()

    except IntegrityError as exc:
        raise self.retry(exc=exc)
```

The **option_add_vote method** (task) updates the poll-object vote-number value adding 1 to the previous value. So, to avoid concurrency problems, I set the poll queue concurrency to 1. This allow the system to handle thousand of vote requests to be completed successfully.

The problem will be, as I can imagine, a bottle-neck when the system grows up.

So, I was thinking about some kind of dynamic queues where all vote requests to any options of a certain poll where routered to a custom queue. I think this will make the system more reliable and fast.

What do you think? How can I make it?

**EDIT1:**

I got a new idea thanks to [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2774965/paul) and [Plahcinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590949/plahcinski). I'm storing the votes as objects in their own model (a user-options relationship). When someone votes an option it creates an object from this model, allowing me to count how many votes an option has. This free the system from the **voting-concurrency** problem, so it could be executed in parallel.

I'm thinking about using **CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE** to cron a task that updates poll options based on the result of `Vote.objects.get(pk=pk).count()`. Maybe I could execute it every hour or do partial updates for those options that are getting new votes...

But, how do I give to the clients updated options in real time?
As [Plahcinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590949/plahcinski) says, I can have a cached value for my options in Redis (or any other mem-cached system?) and use it to temporally store this values, giving to any new request the cached value.

How can I mix this with my standar values in django models? Anyone could give me some code references or hints?
**Am I in the good way or did I make mistakes?**

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is remove your incrementation for the database and move to redis and use the database model as your cached value. Have a celery beat that updates recently incremented redis keys to your database

http://redis.io/commands/INCR

Answer (score 0):

What about just having a simple model that stores vote -1/+1 integers  then a celery task that reconciles those with the FK object for atomic transactions and updates?